# Identical duplicate point lights, different output?

Tags: lighting

I just placed identical, linked (Alt-D) copies of point lights on a ceiling.
[image]

The "source" light is much brighter in renders. Is that some point light "special" again, like the ugly refelections?

[image]

Cheers!

Comment: can u please provide blend file so we can check it out? i assume different node setup or maybe some blocking objects?

Comment: Lights are/seem absolutely identically set up, view the screenshots - same Z-height, just covered by one ceiling object. I'm not allowed to share it as is, but I'll chop it down a bit for upload!

Comment: Looks like the other lights have a glass mesh around them.

Comment: No, they're all exactly the same. I had Alt-D duplicated them and placed them via axis constraints - I just moved the bright one out of the lamp body to see if that made a difference. 
The solution apparently was to Shift-D duplicate them. Now they all look the same. Should I file a bug report?

Answer (score 0):

The solution apparently was to <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>D</kbd> duplicate them.

It seems like it is not possible to duplicate point lights linked with them actually showing in the render - though the IES patterns displayed normally.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)